# Scrape specific value from a json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm looking to scrape some stuff from this example, my goal is to scrape just some values and focus on them by matching the **title** that's inside of the json file (e.g 5.5/6), i would like to let my script pick just values for the section which has as **title** and **option1/2/3** the number 6

```
({
    "id": 39430269435981,
    "title": "5.5",
    "option1": "5.5",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "sku": "195241242248",
    "requires_shipping": true,
    "taxable": true,
    "featured_image": null,
    "available": false,
    "name": "Nike Dunk High 1985 - Lemon Drop / Black / Saturn Gold - 5.5",
    "public_title": "5.5",
    "options": ["5.5"],
    "price": 13108,
    "weight": 1361,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "barcode": null
},
{
    "id": 39430269468749,
    "title": "6",
    "option1": "6",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "sku": "195241242255",
    "requires_shipping": true,
    "taxable": true,
    "featured_image": null,
    "available": false,
    "name": "Nike Dunk High 1985 - Lemon Drop / Black / Saturn Gold - 6",
    "public_title": "6",
    "options": ["6"],
    "price": 13108,
    "weight": 1361,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "barcode": null
}
```

How can i do that? How can i scrape just the **id** of the part where the title is **6**?

Comment: Is there a reason why `beautifulsoup` is tagged here? I assume this is just a JSON question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a more specific method in your case, but the generic method is transform this "json" into a list of dicts and iterate through them, example:

```
import json

jstring = '''
[
{
    "id": 39430269435981,
    "title": "5.5",
    "option1": "5.5",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "sku": "195241242248",
    "requires_shipping": true,
    "taxable": true,
    "featured_image": null,
    "available": false,
    "name": "Nike Dunk High 1985 - Lemon Drop / Black / Saturn Gold - 5.5",
    "public_title": "5.5",
    "options": ["5.5"],
    "price": 13108,
    "weight": 1361,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "barcode": null
},
{
    "id": 39430269468749,
    "title": "6",
    "option1": "6",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "sku": "195241242255",
    "requires_shipping": true,
    "taxable": true,
    "featured_image": null,
    "available": false,
    "name": "Nike Dunk High 1985 - Lemon Drop / Black / Saturn Gold - 6",
    "public_title": "6",
    "options": ["6"],
    "price": 13108,
    "weight": 1361,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "barcode": null
}
]
'''
jlist = json.loads(jstring)

for jdict in jlist:
    if ( jdict['title'] == "6" ):
        print(jdict['id'])
```

output

```
39430269468749
```